# Ajax TabContainer Question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Question:

- I added an ajax tabcontainer control to my aspx page, the first tab appears, but not the second or third tabs appear when I click on it? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to style your tabs? If you're using divs for your tab content, try tables. I had my tabs styled with divs and hit the same problem. This may just be a workaround, but it works!

Comment: The first tab appears which is in divs, but the second and third doesn?